# How to reset the weights of a graph without having to reset/delete the whole graph in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been using `tf.reset_default_graph()` to test out several graphs/models. However, now I would like to train the same model/graph, on different datasets. Therefore, I would like to reset the weights of the created model without having to delete and then create the whole model again. Please note that, I am going to train the model on 20 different datasets. Therefore, maybe resetting the weights only is a simpler operation than deleting the existing model and creating a new one for each dataset. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Building the graph as well as reseting it fast enough. Why would you want do to such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/341), there is no single function to do it, but the offered workaround is to save your initial weights, then use it to re-initialize them alter (rather than randomly re-initializing them each time).

Initially,

```
Winit = weights.get_weights() # do this once before training
```

Later,

```
weights.set_weights(Winit)    # call each time to reset weights
```

Comment: Do you mean I should keep a reference for all the weights in my graph, save the initial values (which is random), and then after training, use the `set_weights` for resetting? Second, `weights.set_weights(Winit)` should be run within a `session` right? Thank you @cs95 for your answer